# Jquery Continuous vertical text scroller that refreshes content

Tags: jquery, refresh, scroller, vticker

I have been trying to adapt JQuery to do what I want, and after spending hours trying to find the answer, am appealing to my betters.  I am using vticker to create a continuously scrolling display.  This information updates every 60 - 90 seconds, but can vary in length.  So I'm looking for one of two things:

1) Display first iteration of A-Z data, and when Z starts to scroll on the screen, immediately grab the next iteration of A-Z data, so iteration #2 of A immediate follows iteration #1 of Z.

2) Simply reload the next iteration of data after a timed interval, but not display it until the previous iteration has completed.

I am pretty adept in PHP, so I can either have the data returned from a PHP script, or from a static HTML file which my PHP script creates.

UPDATE:

Here is my code.  It mostly works - except that if we're in the middle of a list it will refresh those entries on the spot.  For example, assume my list is A-Z, but only F-N are on the screen.  When the refresh fires, it updates the F-N on my screen rather than waiting until the W-X-Y-Z is making its way up from the bottom.

Code:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var $scroller = $("#scroller");
    $scroller.vTicker('init', {height: 350, showItems: 2, speed: 600, pause: 0, mousePause: false });
    $("#scroller").load("stand1.php"); // /Main_Page #jq-p-Getting-Started li");

    $(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug.  without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
setInterval(function() {
$('#scroller').load('stand1.php');
}, 30000); // the "3000" here refers to the time to refresh the div.  it is in milliseconds. 
}); 


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used [DataTables](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/scroll_y_infinite.html) to give infinite scroll to my tables. Also it gives you four [options](http://datatables.net/usage/#data_sources) to load data into tables. And the best thing about "DataTables" is you can theme it using jQueryUI.

Comment: Thanks, but I need this to scroll unattended - think a vertical MARQUEE tag - though I will definitely keep this in mind for another project!